# Scheduling asynchronous tasks in Java Play 2.4.2: scala Duration compilation error

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, akka

I'm using the Akka system scheduler in Play 2.4.2 to execute an asynchronous task. The docs say to use the `scala.concurrent.duration.Duration` class to create a unit of time, but I am getting a compilation error that says I cannot create an instance of `Duration` because it is an abstract class.

This is the block of code that I want to execute asynchronously:

```
Akka.system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(NO_DELAY, workerHandler, Akka.system().dispatcher());
```

`NO_DELAY` is defined as so:

`private static final Duration NO_DELAY = new Duration.create(0, "seconds");`

And relevant import statements:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

The error message:

```
scala.concurrent.duration.Duration is abstract; cannot be instantiated
[error] new Duration(0, "seconds")
```

Any ideas how to use `Duration` properly?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instanciate `Duration` since it is an abstract class, so you need to drop the `new` keyword.

Therefore, you can do:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration;

private static final Duration NO_DELAY = Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Or even:

```
private static final Duration NO_DELAY = Duration.Zero();
```

Comment: Seems like it can't find `FiniteDuration`: `cannot find symbol
[error]   symbol:   class FiniteDuration
[error]   location: package akka.util`

Comment: True, it was in an older version. I updated my answer. Does it solve your problem? :)

Comment: Let me know if none of these help.

Comment: I posted my solution below - thanks for all your help! Looks like things changed significantly in Scala 2.11.6.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like since the upgrade to Scala 2.11.6, FiniteDuration is a class and can be instatiated. The `create` method no longer exists for the Duration abstract class. I solved my problem by using this instead:

```
 private static final FiniteDuration NO_DELAY = new FiniteDuration(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 private static final FiniteDuration FREQUENCY = new FiniteDuration(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

No change to `import` statements.